# How to integrate HikariCP in Dropwizard 1.3.8 application?

Tags: maven, bundle, dropwizard, hikaricp

I have issue with implementing HikariCP in my Dropwizard 1.3.8 app. Project uses Maven as build tool so I've added following dependency from this https://github.com/mtakaki/dropwizard-hikaricp/tree/1.3.x link:

```xml
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mtakaki</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-hikaricp</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.8</version>
  </dependency>
```

...under my `dependencies` tag. As mentioned in link I'm supposed to get:

> INFO  [2016-03-14 06:32:06,681] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @1894ms
> INFO  [2016-03-14 06:32:08,675] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource: hibernate - Starting...

message in my logs but unfortunatelly I don't. Do I need to create some kind of **Bundle** and if yes how (simple example would be nice), if not then what else?
Any kind of help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When in doubt about how to use something and the docs aren't great, I look at [the tests](https://github.com/mtakaki/dropwizard-hikaricp/blob/48c706564d2ed55607c17a35a37bd96ce1323598/src/test/java/io/dropwizard/db/ManagedPooledDataSourceTest.java#L109-L143).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but in my case I'm not experienced with Dropwizard.  Also I'm not using Hibernate, but jDBI3 for data mapping and no Dependency Injection (I'm instantiating needed classes manually in `run()` method of App's Main class) since my RESTful web app is small. Can you please provide more concrete-simple example on how to integrate HikariCP in my app?

Comment: https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/jdbi3.html

Comment: That's very vague and not specific example. Also, I'm using Dropwizard **1.3.8 version** and **latest** one (which you've linked) is **2.x**.